# How are unnatural amino acids modelled using insilico tools?

Tags: bioinformatics

When the structure of an unknown protein containing amino acids other than the 20 known natural amino acids is modelled which method is primarily used in bioinformatics to solve the structure? what is the significance of such model obtained??

Comment: when you say "unnatural amino acids" do you mean those not found in humans or just non-protein coding, or something else? can you clarify?

Comment: You use the words "modelling" and "solve the structure" and refer to "bioinformatics tools" and an "unknown protein" but it's not clear to me what you mean, and I suspect you are not clear either. Presumably you have the sequence of the protein and it contains something like selenocysteine. Are you talking about prediction of the structure de novo from the sequence or trying to impose the sequence on a similar protein of known structure? Why do you think a modified amino acid would cause a problem? You'll have to explain if you want an answer.

Answer (score 1):

An [amino acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amino_acid) is an organic molecule containing a carboxylic acid ($-COOH$) group on one end and an amine ($-NH_2$) on the other end. There exist in nature many more amino acids than the 20 [proteinogenic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proteinogenic_amino_acid) α-amino acids. Examples include [selenocysteine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenocysteine), [pyrrolysine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrrolysine), and [carnitine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnitine). The structure and character of these are all known, so there would be no difference in the computer model from a "standard" amino acid like [threonine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threonine). They are not "mysterious" or "unnatural" at all.

Comment: In nature we have only 20 amino acids, but there is one more amino acid which is synthesised in laboratory

Comment: @Nik did you even read my answer? I defined what an amino acid is in chemistry terms, and provided evidence that there are 20 proteinogenic amino acids, and many more *that occur naturally*. There is an essentially infinite number of amino acids that can be chemically synthesized, varying the length of the carbon backbone, its structure, and the nature and chirality of the side chain(s).